# Get JPAQuery results as a Page

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, pagination, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPAQuery that I can't transform into a spring `findBy...` query. I managed to get only the small amount of results requested using `offset` and `limit`. The problem is that in order to have an actual pagination of my results, I need the same data that I would get with spring repository methods (total number of results and nb of pages). My code looks like this right now:

```
public List<Long> findByCountryId(Long countryId, Pageable pageable) {
    JPAQuery<Long> query = new JPAQuery<>(this.entityManager);
    // innerJoins, where, ...
    query
            .offset(pageable.getOffset())
            .limit(pageable.getPageSize());
    return query.fetch();
}
```

I thought about building the page by myself, but I guess that I would have to request the whole result set instead of fetching less than 50 rows, and I could have thousands of results from this query.

Is there a clean way to fetch a Page from a JPAQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what paging in JPA does. First info on count of rows is needed to check whether your offset doesn't exceed the data, then the actual query is run against the data if possible, otherwise exception is thrown.

Comment: What I did as a temporary solution is that I use the `query.fetchCount()` to get the total number of rows, then I add the `offset` and `limit` (didn't check if the offset is correct according to the nb of rows yet) and I run the query again with the `fetch()`. If I understand what you're saying, that's what JPA would do and consequently, this is a clean solution?

Comment: Yes, those are equivalent

Answer (score 0):

I might be possible to implement easier with a help of specification but do not know because I am a bit unsure what you actually need. Anyway, see the following repository, a specification on it and especially what interfaces it implements:

```
public interface SomeEntityRepository extends Repository<SomeEntity, Long>,
    PagingAndSortingRepository<SomeEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<SomeEntity> {

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static Specification<SomeEntity> findByCountryIdSpecification(Long countryId) {
        return new Specification<SomeEntity>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<SomeEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                // implement query logic with "countryId" here
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
//  there will be a method like below with JpaSpecificationExecutor
//  Page<SomeEntity> findAll(Specification<SomeEntity> specification, Pageable pageable);
}
```

With correctly designed specification the usage of pageable is easy:

```
repo.findAll(SomeEntityRepository.findByCountryIdSpecification(countryId), pageable);
```